# Identify Login Cookie - Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, cookies

My application works based on Single Sign On login technique. But When I go to browser's developer tools, it shows both Asp.Net_SessionID and .ASPXAUTH in cookies tab. I want to secure the cookie flag.

I am not sure whether my application uses the default ASP.Net session ID or Forms Authentication Cookie (e.g ASPXAUTH).

How to identify primary login cookie and how to secure. Any suggestion please.

Comment: You don't know whether you use Forms Authentication or not? And it's your application? How is that even possible? Open up Chrome, go to your app, login, open the Developer Console and see the cookies registered by your app.

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto - As I said, we are using SSO Login mechanism and not Forms Authentication. Just I would like to know Where I can Identify login cookie from browser. If possible can you please post sample screenshot here.

Comment: SSO, single sign on? Which single sign in? This isn't a technology it's a technique used by virtually everyone. We're going to need a lot more information here. It sounds like you don't know how you app works, I'm not sure how we're supposed to know any better.

Comment: @Liam - Sorry for the inconvenience. You are right. My application uses Single sign on. My basic question is when I use developer tools in browser it shows both Asp.Net_SessionID and .ASPXAUTH in Cookies tab. I am not sure for which one I need to set secure flag.

Comment: If it's a security audit, set them both to SSL. The only time you don't want to set this is if your not using SSL. Just set the secure flag (`<httpCookies requireSSL="true" />`) in your config and forget all about it.

Comment: @Liam , One clarifiacation here, Will this code reset Asp.Net_SessionID value?

Comment: I don't follow. Changing the web.config will restart the app pool. This value doesn't affect the usage of the cookie on the server. It just changes how SSL will process it.

Answer (score 1):

In Gloabl.asax file, within `Session_start` method, set `Asp.net_SessionID.secure = true`. This will resolve your problem.

Comment: I would like to identify, login cookie first. Then I can configure accordingly.